# Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am using Angular 2.

When I use this in SCSS file, it works well.

```
.text::after {
  content: "\00a0\00a0";
}
```

However, when I move it in

```
styles: [``]
```

It shows:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.

I know codes in ``` styles: [``] ``` needs to be CSS codes.

And I tried

```
styles: [`
    .text::after {
      content: "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
`]
```

But then the screen shows `&nbsp;&nbsp;` directly. How can I write it correctly?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to escape it

```
.text::after {
  content: "\\00a0\\00a0";  // now it's just a simple plain string
}
```

---

["use strict"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) is a new feature introduced in JavaScript 1.8.5 (ECMAScript version 5).

In which,

- Octal numeric literals are not allowed
- Escape characters are not allowed
- [see more...](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp)

Comment: W3schools is notorious for false information and bad practices, link to Mozilla MDN instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Answer (score 3):

Or you can add `u` *(unicode)* before the `\`.

```js
  .text::after {
    content: "\u00a0\u00a0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with \00a0 value, because it is not octal number (octal characters are 0-7), but it is a hexadecimal number, so use this:

```
.text::after {
  content: "\x00a0\x00a0";
}
```