# How do I find the UTF-8 version of the Octal '\033c'

Tags: javascript, octal

I am working on a Javscript project with the following code...

```
process.stdout.write('\033c');
```

The IJ tooltip says

```
Octal escape sequences are not allowed
```

So I am pretty sure I just need to convert the `\033c` to UTF-8 but since it is kind of a weird char I am not sure I am understanding things properly.

I tried this...

```
process.stdout.write("\\033c");
```

per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878850/octal-literals-are-not-allowed-in-strict-mode) but it still has the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to with UTF-8. `\033c` is supposed to be two characters: `\033` (the ESC control character, code point U+001B) and `c` (a regular lower-case c).

The error says that octal escape sequences are not allowed, so let's use hex instead. Octal 33 converted to hexadecimal is 1B, so you can use `\x1b`*. In combination with the `c` you get `\x1bc`.

For more information, see [the section about escape sequences on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_sequences).

<sub>*: You could also use `\u001b` instead of `\x1b` but for characters in the range of U+0000 to U+00FF it doesn't matter.</sub>