# Escape special characters of column values in single SQL query

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have a table like:

| id | login | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | *@mail.co | 230 |
| 39 | state}.com | 340 |

I need to replace (escape) special characters of `login` column cells like in this
JS method:
`strstr.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&")`.

Using `knexjs` library with Postgres DB, I tried the next query:

```
knex('orders')
      .update({
        login: knex.raw(`REPLACE(login, '/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g', '\\$&')`)
        // or another 
        login: knex.raw(`REPLACE(login, regexp_match(login, '/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g'), '\\$&')`)
      })
```

Both variants returns an error about REPLACE: `replace(character varying, text[], unknown) does not exist`.

I also tried another method:
`update "orders" set "login" = REGEXP_REPLACE(login,'[-[]{}()*+$1.,\\^$|#s]', '\\$&', 'g');` - it returns an error about invalid Regex. This query works without `+` sign in the middle:
`update "orders" set "login" = REGEXP_REPLACE(login,'[-[]{}()*$1.,\\^$|#s]', '\\$&', 'g');`.

Is it possible (after all) to use regex during such SQL query to escape special symbols?

Answer (score 1):

```js
knex('orders')
      .update({
        login: knex.raw(`login=regexp_replace(login,'(\W)','\\\\\1','g')`)
      })
```

The *pattern* [`\W`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE) is shorthand for `[^[:word:]]`, so it's looking for all non-word characters ([`word`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS) class includes alphanumericals `[a-zA-Z0-9]` plus underscore `_`). First four of the five backslashes in *replacement* produce a double backslash before the hit, which ends up evaluated as a single backslash before the hit. `'g'` is there to apply that to all hits.

[Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/NTPF3qrd)

```
create table orders (
  id int generated by default as identity primary key,
  login text,
  amount int);

insert into orders (id,login,amount) values 
(22,'*@mail.co',230),
(39,'state}.com',340);

update orders set login=regexp_replace(login,'(\W)','\\\\\1','g')
returning *;
```

| id | login | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | \*\@mail\.co | 230 |
| 39 | state\}\.com | 340 |

In PostgreSQL, regular [`replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.29.1.1.1) doesn't support POSIX regular expression syntax, [`regexp_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.23.1.1.1) does.

Comment: As per your remark in [the new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77584184/5298879), to stop js from evaluating sequences starting with a backslash, you might need to double them all once more: '\\\\\\\\\\1' as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878850/octal-literals-are-not-allowed-in-strict-mode).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/regexp_replace/) function instead of just `REPLACE`.

For example:

```
knex.raw(`REGEXP_REPLACE(login, '/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g', '\\$&')`)
```

Your regex needs to a POSIX regex, not a JS regex. Test it in psql before using it in knex. This [cheatsheet](https://remram44.github.io/regex-cheatsheet/regex.html) may also be useful.

Comment: [but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer#:~:text=but%20please%20add%20context%20around%20the%20link%20so%20your%20fellow%20users%20will%20have%20some%20idea%20what%20it%20is%20and%20why%20it%E2%80%99s%20there.)