# Creating regular expression string from varchar string using SQL query

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

As a continue of a question [Escape special characters of column values in single SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77581023/escape-special-characters-of-column-values-in-single-sql-query) I have another task:

I have to create Regex expressions from a varchar column values as:

```
* -> ^(.*)$

*@mailhost.com -> ^(.*@mailhost\.com)$

admin@mailhost.com -> ^(admin@mailhost\.com)$
```

So, from asterix symbol to dot+asterix and so on, also surrounded by `^()$`.
How can I do that in a single or multiple SQL queries against Postgres DB?

I am using `knex.js` so I tried variations of the following method:

```
knex('orders')
    .update({
      email: knex.raw(`regexp_replace(email,'(\W)(?<!@)','\\\\\1','g')`),
    });

knex('orders')
    .update({
      email: email: knex.raw(`replace(email,'\\*','.*')`),
    });
```

Oh, and JS does not allow me to use `\\\\\1` sequence because `Octal escape squence are not allowed`. I am using `\x01` instead of it but with no result.

Comment: Small remark: `\W` already contains/matches/targets characters `?<!@`. If you expect `(?<!@)` expression to match any of the characters inside the parentheses, you probably want `[?<!@]` instead: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/iWsI3EoU). Otherwise that's looking for a chain of those exact four characters, in that exact order. Also, please close the old thread by accepting an answer, or address what's wrong with them - your last sentence sounds like you should mention it there.

Comment: @Zegarek about (?<!@) - I would like to escape all special symbols but without at (@)-sign. I tried to match all symbols `\W` and exclude `@` - according to my task, all but not touch `@`

Answer (score 0):

If you're only after asterisks, you can do what you did in the previous thread, and just wrap each login with the remaining part of the expression. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/8atGPN0D)

```js
knex('orders')
    .update({
      email: knex.raw(`concat( '^('
                               ,replace( regexp_replace(login,'(\W)','\\\\\1','g')
                                       ,'\*'
                                       ,'.*')
                               ,')$')`),
    });
```

| id | login | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | ^(.*\@mail\.co)$ | 230 |
| 39 | ^(state\}\.com)$ | 340 |
| 40 | ^(admin\@mailhost\.com)$ | 400 |

As to `Octal escape squence are not allowed`: according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878850/octal-literals-are-not-allowed-in-strict-mode) you might need to double the backslashes yet again to stop js from trying to interpret them as anything else.